# Typical Hadoop setup for remote job submission

Tags: linux, windows, hadoop, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

So I am still a bit new to hadoop and am currently in the process of setting up a small test cluster on Amazonaws. So my question relates to some tips on the structuring of the cluster so it is possible to work submit jobs from remote machines.

Currently I have 5 machines. 4 are basically the Hadoop cluster with the NameNodes, Yarn etc. One machine is used as a manager machine( Cloudera Manager). I am gonna describe my thinking process on the setup and if anyone can chime in the points I am not clear with, that would be great.

I was thinking what was the best setup for a small cluster. So I decided to expose only one manager machine and probably use that to submit all the jobs through it. The other machines will see each other etc, but not be accessible from the outside world. I am have conceptual idea on how to do this,but I am not sure how to properly go about doing this though, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would great.

Also another big point is, I want to be able to submit jobs to the cluster through exposed machine from a client machine (might be Windows). I am not so clear on this setup as well. Do I need to have Hadoop installed on the machine in order to use the normal hadoop commands, and to write/submit jobs say from Eclipse or something similar.

So to sum it up my questions are,

1. Is this an ok setup for a small test cluster
2. How can I go about using one  exposed machine to submit/route jobs to the cluster, without having any of the Hadoop nodes on it.
3. How do I setup a client machine to submit jobs to a remote cluster, and an example on how to do it on Windows. Also if there are any reason not to use Windows as a client machine in this setup.

Thanks I would greatly appreciate any advice or help on this.

Comment: Are you stil looking for an answer or already way ahead in development. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not answered I will attempt to answer it.

### 1. Rest api to submit an application:

Resource 1(Cluster Applications API(Submit Application)): https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Applications_APISubmit_Application

Resource 2: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_yarn-resource-management/content/ch_yarn_rest_apis.html

Resource 3: https://hadoop-forum.org/forum/general-hadoop-discussion/miscellaneous/2136-how-can-i-run-mapreduce-job-by-rest-api

Resource 4: [Run a MapReduce job via rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341185/run-a-mapreduce-job-via-rest-api)

### 2. Submitting hadoop job from  client machine

Resource 1: https://pravinchavan.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/submitting-hadoop-job-from-client-machine/

### 3. Sending program to remote hadoop cluster

It is possible to send the program to a remote Hadoop cluster for running it. All you need to ensure is that you have set the resource manager address, fs.defaultFS, library files, and mapreduce.framework.name correctly before running the actual job.
Resource 1: ([how to submit mapreduce job with yarn api in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767854/how-to-submit-mapreduce-job-with-yarn-api-in-java))