# Run a MapReduce job via rest api

Tags: rest, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I use hadoop2.7.1's rest apis to run a mapreduce job outside the cluster. This example "http://hadoop-forum.org/forum/general-hadoop-discussion/miscellaneous/2136-how-can-i-run-mapreduce-job-by-rest-api" really helped me. But when I submit a post response, some strange things happen:

1. I look at "http://master:8088/cluster/apps" and a post response produce two jobs as following picture:
   [strange things: a response produces two jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8kI6.png)
2. After wait a long time, the job which I defined in the http response body fail because of FileAlreadyExistsException. The reason is another job creates the output directory, so Output directory hdfs://master:9000/output/output16 already exists.

This is my response body:

```
{
    "application-id": "application_1445825741228_0011",
    "application-name": "wordcount-demo",
    "am-container-spec": {
        "commands": {
            "command": "{{HADOOP_HOME}}/bin/hadoop jar /home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar wordcount /data/ /output/output16"
        },
        "environment": {
            "entry": [{
                "key": "CLASSPATH",
                "value": "{{CLASSPATH}}<CPS>./*<CPS>{{HADOOP_CONF_DIR}}<CPS>{{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}}/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}}/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}}/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_YARN_HOME}}/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>{{HADOOP_YARN_HOME}}/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>./log4j.properties"
            }]
        }
    },
    "unmanaged-AM": false,
    "max-app-attempts": 2,
    "resource": {
        "memory": 1024,
        "vCores": 1
    },
    "application-type": "MAPREDUCE",
    "keep-containers-across-application-attempts": false
}
```

and this is my command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://master:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps?user.name=hadoop -d @post-json.txt
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the map reduce, see that you do not have output folder as the job will not run if it is present. You can write program so that you can delete the folder is it exists, or manually delete it before calling the rest api. This is just to prevent the data loss and avoid overwriting the output of other job.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not my answer. Before I call the rest api to run my map-reduce job, the output doesn't exist. When I call, it produces two same job except the job names are different. I don't know why this happens. Maybe the response body I wrote is  wrong somewhere.